# Minimum Hamming distance

Tags: performance, python-3.x, hamming-distance

I started learning Python 3 a few days ago, so if my code is poor I apologise.

I have written a script to find the minimum [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of strings in a list.  Now the strings I will be using are binary words of the same length, so my first question is there a bitwise solution to this in Python?

Secondly, is my code correct and, if so, what's the best approach to boost efficiency?  My searches did not return Python 3 answers, which is why I ask here.

```
def min_ham_dist(a):
    min_dist = len(a[0]) # Defaults minimum distance to maximum length of string.
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(i+1, len(a)): # Compares all words after ith word.
            dist = 0
            for k in range(len(a[i])): 
                if a[i][k] != a[j][k]:
                    dist += 1            
            if dist < min_dist:
                min_dist = dist
    return min_dist
```

Many thanks

Comment: Can the integers have arbitrary length? Or do they have a maximum length?

Comment: In this case they are fixed.  I wrote this to solve a fairly simple problem with a list of 16 binary words of length 12.  It was supposed to be solved by sight, but I felt a script would be best to reduce human error.  It would be nice to see the script applicable for arbitrary lengths though.

Comment: There's a nice and succinct Python 3 example right on that wikipedia page ;) It shows basically what you need to make this work: use `zip()` to zip the two input strings if they have the same length, then compare each pair in the zip, keeping count of how many are unequal.

Comment: Right there in front of my nose!  I just linked the Wikipedia page for reference and didn't consider reading it myself.  Thank you, Dartmouth.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use scipy (pdist) for this, but you have to change input to 2D array. it returns hamming distance as fraction. For this you need strings with numbers (binary strings are ok):

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def min_ham_dist(a):
    return min(pdist([list(i) for i in a], 'hamming'))*len(a[0])
```